# How to check if player wrote something in the input field?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need the player to write down his name first, before clicking play on the pre made button that unity has.

```cs
public void GetNextScene()
{
    if (InputPlayerName != null)
    {
        _playerName = InputPlayerName.text;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(NextScene);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Please, write your name first");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why i always have to find the answer when i go and make my question here... I just did if (InputPlayerName.text != "Enter name") That solved for me.

Comment: You can delete the question, right? Or you can answer your own question and then accept the answer

Comment: `if (InputPlayerName != null)` checks if the input field is null, not its contents.

Comment: Draco18s I don't know how to do that.....

Answer (score 1):

You may want to enable and disable the button dynamically as the player changes text in the input field.

You have to use onValueChanged event, [this one](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html) if you use regular Input fields and [this one](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_onValueChanged) if you use TextMesh Pro.

Example from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField mainInputField;

    public void Start()
    {
        //Adds a listener to the main input field and invokes a method when the value changes.
        mainInputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {ValueChangeCheck(); });
    }

    // Invoked when the value of the text field changes.
    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {
        Debug.Log("Value Changed");
    }
}
```